# Screen flickering in opera when scrolling with .animate .scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, parallax

Here is the website im working on:
http://kognitek.nazwa.pl/stockize/mak/MMprodukcja/parallaxProject/stronaTestowa/test.html

The site is flickering while **scrolling down with arrow keys** on opera.
Here is the code i use for scrolling:

```
//bottom of index.html
else if ($.browser.opera) {

    $(function() {
        $('html').on('keydown', function(event) {
            var keypressed = event.keyCode;
            var curScroll = $('html').scrollTop();
            var keys = scrollKeys.length;
            var moved = false;
            console.log("keypressed: " + keypressed);
            for (i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
                console.log("curScroll: " + curScroll)
                if (moved === false) {
                    if (keypressed === 40 && i != (keys - 1) && parseInt(scrollKeys[i]) <= curScroll && parseInt(scrollKeys[i + 1]) > curScroll) {
                        $('html').animate({
                            scrollTop : (parseInt(scrollKeys[i + 1]))
                        }, 'slow', function() {});
                        console.log('down');
                        moved = true;
                    } else if (keypressed === 38 && i != 0 && parseInt(scrollKeys[i]) >= curScroll && parseInt(scrollKeys[i - 1]) < curScroll) {
                        $('html').animate({
                            scrollTop : (parseInt(scrollKeys[i - 1]))
                        }, 'fast', function(){});
                        console.log('up');
                        moved = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

}
```

I already spent some time trying to fix this and still cant find a reason for this behavior. Site works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE8, IE9. Problem occurs only in Opera. I know i got this part of code x3 at the end of my index.html, gonna optimize this as soon as i find solution.

Any idea whats wrong here?

#### Edit:

I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mymlyn/Mr5vR/ At first, script seems fine, but when you reach the bottom, and try to go up again, screen starts to flicker

#### Edit2:

I think its prevent default issue, working this out atm

#### EditX:

I wish i didnt fail editing this file so it didnt became a community wiki... anyways i upgraded the code and its available here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/swayiqbq/2
It uses .browser thats gonna be removed from jquery 1.9.

Comment: Shouldn't the script act onkeypress instead of onkeyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some code to prevent default behavior in opera:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(code === 40 || code === 38){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Effect can be seen here: 
http://kognitek.nazwa.pl/stockize/mak/MMprodukcja/parallaxProject/stronaTestowa/test_all.html

Its possible to scroll down/up, and it works as supposed to!

Gonna optimise this and make it a snippet in a few days :)